# What does 'the event loop checks to see if the task is returning control to other JavaScript code' in Microtask MDN document?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide

I'm looking at MDN document about using microtasks in Javascript with microtask and there is  one paragraph I do not really get it.

That sentence is

> First, each time a task exits, the event loop checks to see if the
> task is returning control to other JavaScript code.

where it explains the difference between macrotask and microtask.

What does `returning control to other JS code` means? I think it means if there is callback function then callback function are executed not the microtask, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: I think that's worded in a way that could be improved. I'll fire up the T. J. Crowder beacon.

Comment: "*it's first useful to know what a **JavaScript task** is*" That doesn't start very well... Tasks aren't a JS construct. To properly comprehend tasks and microtasks (and their difference), it's important to understand that tasks are not part of JS. Tasks will sometimes Call JS callbacks or run a JS ScriptEvaluation or enqueue JS Jobs, but in themselves they're not JS, they belong to the browser's event-loop. What I believe this sentence was meant to convey is that if the current running JS script (callback, job, etc.) was the last on the call-stack, then the microtask queue would be checked.

Comment: But the thing is that this "current running JS script" is not a ["task"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#concept-task) as in WHATWG's event-loop's nomenclature. Here it's being used as a catch-all phrase to mean "what's on the callstack", and it's misleading...